# Mounting problem and slow boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=c549b7a5-952a-4c40-98f6-01d8498f2107 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=b794631e-6515-4346-a8ba-2125299f59d6 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

What should I do?
This problem makes boot take more than  3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the output of following file:

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

and the output of following command:

```
df -h
```

Look at the kernel ring buffer for errors or warnings:

```
dmesg -k
```

To measure and see the startuptime of kernel and userspace (supposing you are using a systemd daemon):

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

This will show you the slowest units.

Comment: # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=c549b7a5-952a-4c40-98f6-01d8498f2107 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=b794631e-6515-4346-a8ba-2125299f59d6 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           787M  9.4M  778M   2% /run
/dev/sda5        70G   25G   42G  38% /
tmpfs           3.9G   25M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           787M   80K  787M   1% /run/user/1000